# what do you use for tinkerpop gremlin ORM and spring data in java

Tags: java, neo4j, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

What is the most recommended way to talk to gremlin server using a java spring data style communication? Microsoft has [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-gremlin), but it has some limitations like no multi-tenancy support that forbid me from using it. This also does not have any updates in the past several months. Looking at other options like [peapod](https://bayofmany.github.io/). [spring-data-neo4j](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-neo4j) is an option too, but i am looking for a vendor agnostic way. I am curious on how other people are solving this. What is the best way to talk to gremlin server in a neat(spring data) way?

Comment: stackoverflow typically doesn't like "tool recommendation" types of questions so i would likely vote to close this question but for folks who use OGMs with Gremlin in Java, I'd say that most folks currently use Ferma: http://syncleus.com/Ferma/

Comment: Thank you @stephenmallette. do you know what people use for cosmosDB? the spring-data-gremlin written by microsoft doesn't support multi-tenancy

Comment: sorry, i'm not aware of anything that might work with CosmosDB aside from what you've listed in spring-data-gremlin.